# Installed c++ libraries and header removed from search paths

Tags: compiling, 19.04, c++

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04. However, somehow I messed something up today and I don't know how to fix it.

If I want to build a c++ program, all headers that are located in a subfolder inside of `usr/include` can't be included anymore without explicitly naming the subfolder. So instead of writing `#include <petsc.h>` I now have to write `#include <petsc/petsc.h>`. The problem is, that the included header in the example includes other headers without adding the subfolder. A lot of other includes seem to be affected too (mpi for example). So I guess I seriously destroyed the standard search paths of my system. Is there any way to fix this or should I reinstall ubuntu?

**EDIT**

Didn't find a solution. So I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 and upgraded to 19.04 before installing anything else. Now everything works as expected.

Greetings